# What is the purpose of the scalar data type in OpenCV?

Tags: c++, opencv, matrix, scalar

I have been looking through the different data types in OpenCV, and came across the Scalar data type.  However, I couldn't figure out *why* this data type exists?

Specifically:

- Isn't scalar by its mathematical definition just a one-dimensional quantity with a magnitude?
- What types of operations is it supposed to be used for (vs. a 4-dimensional vector)?
- If conj() returns `(w, -x, -y, -z)` which are the values of the respective elements of the scalar, what do the `x`, `y`, and `z` actually represent?  Imaginary numbers?

Comment: Scalar is used often as input parameter (for example for drawing functions) to provide color information without the need to know the data type and channel number of the image.

Comment: `conj` seems to be there as a nod towards using Scalar to hold a complex number or quaternion - which isn't really its main purpose.